# HDA audio in Qemu for FreeBSD 14

Tags: freebsd, sound-card, qemu

I just installed Qemu in my Linux, and created a virtual machine, and installed FreeBSD 14 on it.

I just enabled HDA audio in the Qemu command line (as seen below), but it doesn't work in the virtual machine. I followed all the steps in the chapter 08 of the FreeBSD Handbook (https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/multimedia/), but it didn't worked at all.

Running the `aplay -l` command (as I installed the alsa-utils package), I got the following message: "no soundcards found"

Running the `cat /dev/sndstat` command, I got the following message: "no devices installed from userspace".

I invoked Qemu with the following command line:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd -m 1900 -hda img.raw -device intel-hda -device hda-duplex
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yeah, a lot of times, of course. :)